# saveall with hasOne saves blank foreign key

Tags: cakephp

I have th e following model relationships:

Enquiry:

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'SeminarAttendence' => array(
      'className' => 'SeminarAttendence'
  )  
);
```

SeminarAttendence:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Enquiry' => array(
      'className' => 'Enquiry',
   'foreign_key' => 'enquiry_id',
  )
);
```

my post data looks like this:

```
[Enquiry] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => joe
        [last_name] => soap
        [email_address] => 
        [tel_home] => 
        [tel_work] => 
        [tel_cell] => 
    )

[SeminarAttendence] => Array
    (
        [branch_id] => 178 // this has no table relation it's for a web service
    )
```

I saveAll this  in a controller:

```
$this->Enquiry->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'first', 'atomic' => false
```

when I am done I get result like this in the SeminarAttendence

```
id  branch_id  enquiry_id
1   4               0
2   4               0
3   3               0
4   1               0
```

It worked fine on php5 yesterday, now when i ported it to our dev server (php4 ) it doesnt work?

Comment: nevermind i just did it the old trusted way, saving each model in serial

Answer (score 0):

It's not cakephp problem. because cakephp is made for php4, and works properly on php5. maybe something wrong with datebase, or config